# Create product in printful using API - Python

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

I am trying to a create a product using the Printful api and python. I was able to create a product on there website (a basic) hoodie, and I wanted to try and create the same hoddie using python.

Here is the documentation I am using: https://developers.printful.com/docs/#operation/createSyncProduct

I keep getting this error which is very generalistic:

```
{
    "code": 400,
    "result": "This API endpoint applies only to Printful stores based on the Manual Order / API platform. Find out more at Printful API docs.",
    "error": {
        "reason": "BadRequest",
        "message": "This API endpoint applies only to Printful stores based on the Manual Order / API platform. Find out more at Printful API docs."
    }
}
```

here is the code I am trying for testing:

```
import requests
import json

my_key = "my_token"

headers = {
    "Authorization" : "Bearer "+my_key
}


data = {
            "id": 302079884,
            "external_id": "8136758395169",
            "name": "Unisex Hoodie",
            # "variants": 6,
            "thumbnail_url": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0713/4275/2033/products/unisex-premium-hoodie-black-front-64079acdc1ff0_grande.jpg?v=1678219998",
            "is_ignored": False
        }
data = json.dumps(data)

products = requests.post("https://api.printful.com/store/products",headers=headers,data=data)
print(json.dumps(products.json(),indent=4))
```

I am not sure how to test this code because the response is very generalistic.

I was able to test my token to make sure it works by trying to get the product I made on the website:

```
import requests
import json

my_key = "my_token"

headers = {
    "Authorization" : "Bearer "+my_key
}

products = requests.get("https://api.printful.com/sync/products",headers=headers)
print(json.dumps(products.json(),indent=4))
```

and I got the response:

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "result": [
        {
            "id": 302079884,
            "external_id": "8136758395169",
            "name": "Unisex Hoodie",
            "variants": 6,
            "synced": 6,
            "thumbnail_url": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0713/4275/2033/products/unisex-premium-hoodie-black-front-64079acdc1ff0_grande.jpg?v=1678219998",
            "is_ignored": false
        }
    ],
    "extra": [],
    "paging": {
        "total": 1,
        "offset": 0,
        "limit": 20
    }
}
```

So I know I am hitting the api correctly. If anyone has any suggestions on how to create a basic product using the printful api, that would be awesome.

**EDIT**: I also tried what @Driftr95 mentioned regarding wrapping the data around "sync_product" but that still didn't work. Here is the new data variable now:

```
data = {
    "sync_product": {
        "name": "API product Bella",
        "thumbnail": "https://imagemagick.org/image/wizard.jpg"
    },
    "sync_variants": [
        {
            "retail_price": "21.00",
            "variant_id": 44666144522529,
            "files": [
                {
                    "url": "https://imagemagick.org/image/wizard.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "type": "back",
                    "url": "https://imagemagick.org/image/wizard.jpg"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

but I still get:

```
{
    "code": 400,
    "result": "This API endpoint applies only to Printful stores based on the Manual Order / API platform. Find out more at Printful API docs.",
    "error": {
        "reason": "BadRequest",
        "message": "This API endpoint applies only to Printful stores based on the Manual Order / API platform. Find out more at Printful API docs."
    }
}
```

That response is so vague it is very hard to tell what is wrong with the post data I am trying to send.

Comment: According to the section of the documentation you linked, and as demonstrated with their [sample payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGqAR.png), what you currently have in `data` should be wrapped as **`sync_product`** like `data = {'sync_product': {"external_id": "8136758395169", "name": "Unisex Hoodie", ....}}`. And I don't think you're supposed to be including `id` when creating new products as `id`s are generally generated by the system (by Printful in this case)

Comment: @Driftr95 thank you for pointing that out, however I am still getting the same error. I updated my post to show what the new data variable looks like. I bet you its something small, but since the 400 response is so vague its hard to tell what the issue is. lol

Comment: that leaves me bit stumped as well [I can't test it myself since I don't have a key....] try sending `data` as a string? [ use something like [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) ]

Comment: Thats a good idea but I am actually using that currently. `data = json.dumps(data)`. If I don't I get an error saying the json data is not valid. So I assume they wanted it stringified using json dumps. There documentation is not the best. lol

Also if you want, I can show the api key as its a new account and don't have anything really connected to it. Once its figured out I can change up the key. Let me know if that will work for you

Comment: Idk what else to try tbh - you have all the required fields [`sync_product.name`, `sync_variants.variant_id`, `sync_variants.files.url`]...I'd [contact support](https://www.printful.com/docs/support) at this point if I were you

Comment: I figured out the error I was getting but still can't get it to create a product. I reread the error I was getting again and realized they were talking about the fact that I created an API token key that works with my shopify store. That end point only works on stores that are created through printful directly. So when I created a test store in printful and created a new API key token for that, I got another error. - This time about colors, which isn't in the documentation at all. So I am closer but not there yet. So I sent an email over to dev support for now. Thanks for your help on this!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out the answer on my own. For those running across this issue in the future I figured it would be best to show the code.

First out the issue here:

> {
> "code": 400,
> "result": "This API endpoint applies only to Printful stores based on the Manual Order / API platform. Find out more at Printful API docs.",
> "error": {
> "reason": "BadRequest",
> "message": "This API endpoint applies only to Printful stores based on the Manual Order / API platform. Find out more at Printful API docs."
> }
> }

Is because I was using an API token/key that was directly for shopify. When you create an API key/token for printful, it will ask you what store you want it to apply to. Since I ONLY had a test shopify store at the time, I decided to use that token, but the endpoint I was using doesn't allow you to create products directly from printful into shopify or your ecommerce store. So I created a test store with printful only and used an API key/token that worked for that directly.

I then ran across another issue because I didn't specifiy colors of the hoodie I was trying to create. So I decided to try a mockup which I assume is the most basic thing you can make.

Here is what fixed the code. Try this sample data and this should work:

```
data = {
    "sync_product": {
            "name": "Test Product",
        },
        "sync_variants": [
            {
                "external_id": "44666144522529",
                "variant_id": 10779,
                "retail_price": "31.00",
                "sku": "7563051_10779",
                "files": [
                    {
                        "type": "mockup",
                        "url": None,
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
}
```

from here you can slowly tweak what you need based off the products you can use in printful's catalog.

Comment: was you able to push manual products you created to shopify?